# User data in EC2 is not able to run my py script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a python script which is used to split a video into frames. This python script is executed by a shell script. I have put the execution command for this shell script in the user data of my EC2 instance. However , when I start my instance, the shell script is running but the python script is not running.
I am getting the following error when i check my cloud-init-output.log file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frame_splitter.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
Cloud-init v. 20.4.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 19 Mar 2021 11:09:20 +0000. Up 17.64 seconds.
```

When i run the shell script or the py script locally from the instance, it is running fine. Why is not finding any of the libraries even though it is already installed?

EDIT

This is the user data script

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ubuntu
sh ./panorama.sh
```

Comment: Can you show the user Data script?

Comment: @Marcin I have edited and added the script

Comment: All the python libraries are installed in your local .pip folder? The user-data runs as root very early on after boot. The paths to your libraries could be not initialized.

Comment: I see. So how do i initialize that? I am new to aws so i do not have a clear idea

Comment: Can you install your packages like this:-  pip install --target ./package cv2 it will install the packages/dependencies in the present folder. So, before running you need to do 'cd' and go to your location where the code resides. then run the command.

Comment: @bhavukbhardwaj So basically I should run your command in the directory where the program is and then later run the user data? Or should I install this from the user data itself?

Comment: Not Sure if you have done it. First, you try at your local like how this command works and what it will do . Then it will be your call to where to put it. But please try to do both. First, go to your directory and run that command where your code resides and later automate this step via user data [ec2].

Answer (score 1):

you need add these two steps in your user script after #!/bin/sh

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```